# With Permanent magnet or electrificated sticks to create EM waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I studied that the EM waves run through the space, with each electric field and magnetic field oscillating and inducing each other. And I had thought-experiment that it could be possible to make EM waves with manual steps(or mechanical) -  shaking permanent magnet or electrificated sticks. Is it possbile enough to make EM waves in the way i assumed? If it is, please hyperlink the related research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does waving a magnet around create light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229366/)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes.

The changes in magnetic and electrical fields will propagate outwards at the speed of light. The wavelength is determined by the frequency, so it would depend on how fast you were spinning the magnet. You would have to spin the magnet very, very fast to produce anything other than extremely low frequency radio waves. Even a 10khz signal would need the magnet to spin at 10,000 rps (rotations per second) which is 600,000 rpm. If you are shaking it, you need to shake it a 10^15 times per second to make it emit em waves.

I don't know of any material that wouldn't rip itself apart at that speed.

Source - [rstif350](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/96157/rstif350)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! It would be fun if i could.

Comment: A toothed wheel, with a hundred teeth, would generate 10 kHz if spun at  a mere 100 revolutions per second, 6000 rpm, which is achievable.

Comment: @Whit3rd that's amazing! I will once try when I get to the university.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a moving magnet CAN generate high enough frequency to produce radio.
[This old chart shows moving-parts "long wave" transmitter](http://swling.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/ChartOfElectromagneticRadiation.jpg).

The method is archaic, however, and unlikely to still be in use
anywhere in the world.