How many photons pass through us every second?
I just read this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/229374, which says that, when a magnet rotates, photons are emitted with wavelength $λ=c/f$, where $f$ is the frequency of rotation. And this made me think, if all accelerated charges emit photons, albeit with extremely long wavelengths, how many photons might pass through us every second?

Say we have a beam of ordinary electromagnetic waves, with power $P$. Then the energy passing a plane, each second, is $P$. If it is monochromatic with frequency $\nu$ then the number of photons per second crossing such a plane is
$$
R = \frac{P}{h \nu} = \frac{P}{\hbar \omega}
$$
where I included the second version to make it clear that $h$ is Planck's constant. Now suppose this beam has a cross-sectional area $A$, then the number of photons per second per unit area is
$$
R / A = \frac{P}{\hbar \omega A}
$$
If the beam strikes a person from a roughly horizontal direction then the person presents an area $A_{\rm person} \simeq 0.5\,{\rm m}^2$. So the number of photons from this beam striking a person per second is
$$
R \frac{A_{\rm person}}{A} = \frac{P A_{\rm person}}{\hbar \omega A}
$$
At many wavelengths these photons are absorbed. Those that pass through are mostly at long wavelengths (so low frequency, i.e. radio waves). The transmission is pretty high at frequencies below 500 MHz (microwave ovens typically operate at $2.45$ GHz and may use $915$ MHz).
Let's apply the above to a mobile phone emitting 1 watt at 500 MHz. About half the emission may pass through a person. That's about $0.5 P / \hbar \omega = 10^{24}$ radio-wave photons per second. I am guessing that will be the main contribution if someone is making a call or otherwise using their phone. I haven't done the calculation for radio and television broadcasts. Near a big antenna that will also be significant. (I remember standing at the top of the Eiffel tower and trying to listen to a walkman through headphones (if anyone can remember those things); all I could hear was interference from the nearby microwave antennas. It made me wonder what those same waves were doing to my head.)
There are also fields oscillating at 50 Hz, produced by all the currents in the wires in a building providing the mains electricity. However the interpretation of those fields in terms of photons is a bit more subtle because they are mostly what we call near-field (as opposed to travelling waves propagating far from their source). However these fields are excited very far above their ground state, and in this sense they have many photons.

Thanks for the answer, but my question was more about the ions and other microscopic charges; because those would also be emitting photons, right?
